# Use of colon after words

Tags: colons

Good afternoon! Let's say I want to give an example and I write :

> Example:
>
> The text of my example.

Am I grammatically correct? Should I use colon after the word example in the text above? What else can I use?

Comment: I prefer For example, in things like that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no mistake in using a colon.  But it is not the only punctuation mark you could use.  A full-stop, or a dash —, or nothing at all would also be fine.

This isn't a matter of grammar, but a matter of clarity in written English.